# Is there a way to extend wagtail's draftail with an entity that generates random numbers on page access?

Tags: python, wagtail

I am extending the wagtail rich text editor, draftail. I want to give the user the ability to insert a `$RANDOM` entity.

The site has a global option to set the random interval, let's call these `random_start` and `random_end`. These values are stored in the database.

When the `$RANDOM` entity is used, I would like the visited page to display a random number between `random_start` and `random_end`.

My current attempt allows me to generate the random number but the generation happens only when the page is published, not accessed. All subsequent page visits show the same number.

Previously (before switching to wagtail) the Django code was simple.
Do the following in page view code:

1. get `random_start`
2. get `random_end`
3. generate random number between them
4. pass generated number to the template

My current 'incomplete' solution is based of http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5.1/advanced_topics/customisation/extending_draftail.html#creating-new-entities.

By modifying `stock_entity_decorator`, I get my current code.

```py
def stock_entity_decorator(props):
    """
    Draft.js ContentState to database HTML.
    Converts the STOCK entities into a span tag.
    """

    return DOM.create_element('span', {
        'data-stock': props['stock'],
    }, str(random.randint(random_start, random_end)))
```

Both, random_start and random_end are values which can change in the database.

I know I can use JavaScript to calculate the number client side. But I am hoping a solution exists which avoids client side calculation as that would introduce other problems.

**Update**

I had simplified the use case a little bit. The random number is not completely random, it is based of a few parameters which should preferably remain secret. Doing the calculation client side would imply disclosing these values.
I thought about setting up a RESTful endpoint and using client-side JavaScript to get the values that way.

For this project I am not concerned with caching and can disable it for the required pages.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to avoid client-side calculation? Calculating this server-side on page view is possible, but this will cause issues if your site’s page views are cached or if you use a CDN. – In those scenarios the random number will always be the same once cached.

Comment: I had simplified the use case a little bit. The random number is not completely random, it is based of a few parameters which should preferably remain secret. Doing the calculation client side would imply disclosing these values.
For this project I am not concerned with caching and can disable it for the required pages.
I added this information to the main post just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to extend Draftail.  Override the `get_context()` method of your `Page`-based model:

```
YourPage(Page):

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['random_number'] = your_random_number_function()

        return context
```

[Wagtail Docs](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5.1/reference/pages/model_reference.html?highlight=model%20reference#wagtail.core.models.Page.get_context)

Comment: I might not have been clear. I want my users to be able to insert the random number from within the rich text editor just like in the linked example.
The user would have the freedom of inserting multiple numbers in his sentence/text.

Comment: As far as I understand, doing it this way would require me to edit the template to include `{{ random_number }}` which I can't do for user generated `{{ self.description|richtext }}`. Hope I am not missing something obvious here.

Comment: This video on extending Draftail might be of use to you:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4M0MEtE_H0&list=PLMQHMcNi6ocsS8Bfnuy_IDgJ4bHRRrvub&index=29

Comment: Both of Kalob Tauliens examples are generated on page save. I have watched all his Wagtail videos and he doesn't return extend on this topic.